# How insert java list value in cassandra using java code?

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh

my cassandra DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE devjavasource.userorders (
user_id text PRIMARY KEY,
name text,
rlist list<text>
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

my code:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class cassandraList
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cluster cluster = null;
        Session session = null;
        cluster = cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.1.23").build();
        List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("fake1@fake1.com");
        list.add("fake2@fake2.com");

        session = cluster.connect("devjavasource");

        System.out.println("test :" +list);

        Statement st = new SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO USERS (user_id, name, Rlist) VALUES ('11101', 'john', "+list+");");

        System.out.println("query :" +"INSERT INTO USERS (user_id, name, Rlist) VALUES ('11101', 'john', "+routing_points+");");
        ResultSet rs = session.execute(st);
    }
```

I got a error, so get query from print statement like this:

```
  INSERT INTO USERS (user_id, name, Rlist) VALUES ('11101', 'john', [AUE, SAN, UK, LON]);
```

Then I run this query to cql manually, I got this error:

> SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:70 no viable alternative at input ',' (...VALUES ('11101', 'john', [[AUE],...)">

Answer (score 2):

Use bind markers:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
list.add("fake1@fake1.com"); 
list.add("fake2@fake2.com"); 
Statement st = new SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO USERS (user_id, name, rlist) VALUES ('11101', 'john', ?);", list); 
ResultSet rs = session.execute(st);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is comprised of strings, this should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (user_id, name, Rlist) VALUES ('11101', 'john', ['AUE', 'SAN', 'UK', 'LON']);
```

Comment: In java how to create the list of string that have single quotes dynamically

Comment: I got java List with out single quotes ,how convert this?

Comment: I would need more information than that. Are you preparing you query? If you could post the code of how you are trying to insert, I could take a look.

Comment: List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("fake1@fake1.com");
    list.add("fake2@fake2.com");

    Statement st = new SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO USERS (user_id, name, Rlist) VALUES ('11101', 'john', "+list+");");
    ResultSet rs = session.execute(st);

Comment: Try using prepared statements instead. They might handle this for you automatically.

Comment: Thank you, i am using prepared statements it working.